# Having trouble rendering a partial comments file in post's show page

Tags: ruby-on-rails

The usual blog, ie, `Posts` and `Comments` ...

Comments belongs to Posts ...

Posts' controller is all typical actions geared towards posts.

Posts' model `has_many` comments

Posts views shows up fine ...

Then I created Comments controller, model, and only two partial view files, ie, `_form.html.erb` and `_comment.html.erb` ...

In Post's `show.html.erb`, I put both of them like this:

```
<h2>Recent Comments</h2>

<%= render @comment.comments %>

<h2>Add Comments</h2>

<%= render 'comments/form' %>
```

That's when I run into this trouble, ie, getting this error when I click on Post's show link ... I get this error:

`NoMethodError in Posts#show` & `undefined method`comments' for nil:NilClass`in reference to this line`<%= render @comment.comments %>`  and I don't know how to solve it ...

**Post's Controller**

```
class PostsController < ApplicationController


    def index 
        @posts = Post.all

        if @posts.blank? 
            flash[:alert] = "No posts have been created."
        else
            @posts 
        end
    end

    def edit 
        @post = Post.find(params[:id])
    end

    def update
        @post = Post.find(params[:id])

        if @post.update(post_params)
            flash[:notice] = "Post has been updated."
            redirect_to @post 
        else
            flash.now[:alert] = "Post has not been updated." 
            render "edit" 
        end
    end

    def create 
        @post = Post.new(post_params)

        if @post.save 
            flash[:notice] = "Post has been created."
            redirect_to @post 
        else
            flash[:notice] = "Post has not been created."
        end
    end

    def new 
        @post = Post.new
    end

    def show 
        @post = Post.find(params[:id])
    end

    def destroy
        @post = Post.find(params[:id])
        @post.destroy 

        flash[:notice] = "Post has been deleted." 
        redirect_to posts_path 
    end


    private 

    def post_params
        params.require(:post).permit(:title, :author, :body)
    end

end
```

**Comments Controller**

```
class CommentsController < ApplicationController


    def create 
        @post = Post.find(params[:post_id])
        @comment = @post.comments.create(comment_params)
        redirect_to post_path(@post)
    end


    private 

        def comment_params
            params.require(:comment).permit(:author, :body)
        end
end
```

**Comments _comment.html.erb**

```
<p>
    Author:
    <%= comment.author %>
</p>
<p>
    Body: 
    <%= comment.body %>
</p>
```

Please let me know if further information is needed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pay attention to what your error is trying to tell you:

`NoMethodError in Posts#show undefined method 'comments' for nil:NilClass regarding <%= render @comment.comments %>`

It is telling you that there is no method `comments` for NilClass. That means that `@comment` is nil. `@comment` is nil because you never define that variable in the respective `Posts#show` action. There, you only have a `@post` variable.

My guess is that what you actually meant to do is: `<%= render @post.comments %>`

Comment: with `<%= @post.comments %>`, I get this error: `undefined method comments' for nil:NilClass`

Comment: So, based on the error, that means I need to insert something about the comments in the `Posts#show` action?

Comment: Okay, so let's continue to debug. *Why* is `@post` nil?

Comment: well, it's because like I said, that the Post#show action needs to have something about the comments?

Comment: You should not need to create a variable in the controller to hold the comments, since you should be able to reach through `@post` that you already have.

Comment: should Post#action be like this: 
  #post = Post.find(params[:id])
  #comment = #post.comments.find(params[:id])

Comment: Are you certain that your associations are setup correctly? From within a rails console, can you do `Post.first.comments` successfully?

Comment: I'm sure my associations are set up correctly ... want me to post the routes, and model files?

Comment: just ran `Post.first.comments` in rails console, it worked.

Comment: If your code is like it is in your original post, there is no reason that changing `@comment.comments` in `posts/show.erb.html` to `@post.comments` should not work. If that *doesn't* work, it means that you are attempting to show a post that doesn't exist in the DB

Comment: What is the URL that you hit when you click on the link that breaks?

Comment: If there is a post in your DB with an ID of 1, then I'm a bit stumped

Comment: there is `irb(main):010:0> Post.first
  Post Load (0.8ms)  SELECT  "posts".* FROM "posts" ORDER BY "posts"."id" ASC LIMIT $1  [["LIMIT", 1]]
=> #<Post id: 1, title: "Post One", body: "Oy!", author: "Tina", created_at: "2017-04-26 21:11:22", updated_at: "2017-04-26 21:11:22">`

Comment: maybe I should post more files from the app?

Comment: Use gist.github.com to post both models, the controller and the views. Lemme also see `routes.rb`

Comment: would it be faster if I gave you my github's link? It's private ... I can add your name?

Comment: Sure, no problem

Comment: what's your github name?

Comment: Can find me by `bholzer`

Comment: I got you. Let me get everything running and I'll see what's up

Comment: Check your pull requests on the project

Comment: hee, before I look at the pull request, let me say how I just solved it right now

Comment: I changed it to this: `<%= render @post.comments %>`

Comment: Haha, so exactly what this answer said to do?

Comment: yup! I'm so glad I figured it out before seeing your answer, otherwise would have felt bad ...

Comment: thank you though for your time! Super appreciate it!

Comment: It's all part of the learning process. Try to focus on actually understanding what your errors tell you. Most of the time, they are pretty descriptive. In this case, it was telling you *exactly* the problem: you were trying to call `.comments` on something that didn't exist.

Comment: never done a pull request ... going to approve this one for fun just to see how the process is like! =)

Comment: I know. Got lost on the fact `.comments` part ... didn't realize it might have been the former part, not the latter ... really need to work on my debugging skills way more!

Comment: wait, what? I didn't realize that approving the change didn't mean the the change would not be merged ... and that you have to merge it ... interesting!

Comment: If this answer helped, please accept it as the correct answer.

Comment: oh good grief! I totally forgot that you wrote this as an answer! Thought this was all in comments underneath my question! Mea culpa!